# jQuery <div> issue

Tags: jquery

I have HTML table structure displaying some records.
There is an "info" (i.e., small 16x16 'i') image, I need following functionality:
Clicking on "info" image should open a div, containing 'more' details about particular/selected transaction
Issue/problem is I need to show div above page contents (like image gallery, when we click on image, other things are black'ed out and a larger image can be seen), with close link.
Can anyone help me achieving this functionality, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I have understood you just need a popUp that is showed when you click on the button.
most of the solution are based on preloading the div the contains the information you want to show against the button click , hide the div itself and show it only when the user press the button. I can suggest you to go for a JQuery solution which wraps all this behaviour

the below is just an example:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/bpopup

Comment: Hi, as you said, I am using bpopup but still have issue, can you help me with it. I need on every "info" image, how can I achieve this?

Comment: If you need it for each image you have 2 solutions:
the first is you have to preload one DiV for each image with the imfomration you need to show on the PopUp.You could concatenate the row id to the DIV'id to guess with popUp you have to show, but it could take longer to load the page.
I think the best solution is populate the DIV (popUp) with an Async call using jquery(to retrive the information you need) before showing the popUp itself

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery dialog

You can get it on

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Answer (score 0):

use [Shadowbox](http://www.shadowbox-js.com) plugin for jquery

Comment: I don't need it for images, it should also contain text or any markup